# execution order of the code below and why?

Tags: javascript, promise

Mainly the order of “promise2” and “async1 end”. I don't know why.

```js
async function async2() {
  console.log("async2");
}
new Promise(resolve => {
  resolve(async2());
}).then(() => {
  console.log("async1 end");
});

new Promise(function(resolve) {
  console.log("promise1");
  resolve();
}).then(function() {
  console.log("promise2");
});
```

Comment: Why do you care? They are independent promise chains, and the callbacks ought to happen in any order.

Comment: For the code I post, I don't think so.

Comment: Promises only give the guarantee that `async 1 end` happens after `async2` and that `promise2` happens after `promise1`. Sure, the implementation is deterministic and one could explain why you get the result you are getting because of the order of queuing things, but you should not *rely* on that. If you need to guarantee order between callbacks, chain them explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 resolve(async2());
```

is briefly the same as:

```
resolve(Promise.resolve())
```

So it creates a Promise that will resolve, and passes that to the resolution of another promise. As Promises get flattened (resolving a promise with a promise, will make the outer promise wait for the inner), your examples could be simplified to:

```
 Promise.resolve("first").then(console.log);

 Promise.resolve("second")
   .then(it => it) 
   .then(console.log);
```

Now resolving a Promise is guaranteed to be asynchronous, so even if you resolve it synchronously like in your case, the `.then` callbacks will only be called after 1 tick. Now the first one will log after one tick, the second one will also resolve after one tick, then the chained Promise will resolve which will then wait another tick till the third one is done.

Therefore “promise2” will be logged after one tick, and  “async1 end” after two ticks.

---

Nevertheless you should not rely on the execution order of promises.

Comment: I know. I just want to know the principle of event loop, and execution order of macro task and micro task. Do you know any documents about it?

Comment: @Angelki The distinction between macro and micro tasks doesn't matter here, you only got promises in the code - all async handlers are processed by the same queue.